# MS Access: How can filter multiple fields in a filtered search (text box)

Tags: ms-access, search, filter, field

I am so stuck on VBA today, i might as well pop the question.
Hopefully someone can help me cause im lost.
It's about the following line specifically:

```
strFilter = "orderstatus Like '*" & _.
```

Orderstatus is the field im searching in (filtering down). 
It works fine, but i would like some other fields in there as well!

```
strFilter = "orderstatus And ordersales Like '*" & _.
```

I tried that???? I tried many things but nothing works

Heres the full code:

```
Private Sub txtFilter_AfterUpdate() Dim strFilter As String
If Len(Trim(Me.txtfilter.Value & vbNullString)) > 0 Then
strFilter = "orderstatus Like '*" & _
Replace(Me.txtfilter.Value, "'", "''") & _
"*'"
Me.Filter = strFilter
Me.FilterOn = True
Else
Me.FilterOn = False
End If
End Sub
```

Please help!!!! Ive been stuck for 4 days already :S

Comment: Where is your strFilter set? What is the problem - syntax error or filter not working? It looks like you are not using the orderstatus field where your example says you want your ordersales field. But we're not sure what you're trying to filter on and what the field types are. Did you want wildcards on both fields?

Comment: Well it works just fine. It gives me the results back.
The problem is that im searching a single field in my form. (Like 1 colomn)
In this case im searching in the orderstatus field, but i would like to add another one to that :S

Why is Access always full of problems and complications?

Comment: There is no problem with Access. It's like any new app - you need to take time to learn the language - or in this case, two languages VBA and SQL. Where are you going to get the filter value for the second field? It sounds like you need multiple filter text fields and a separate "Apply Filter" button that collects and concatenates your filter fields.

Comment: I know. Im into C# right now, ill get there at some point.
Thanks for replying though!.
Anyway, the value i want to get from the same field. Which is the search field (text box) right? I type the value i want to search for in txtFilter, and i want it to look in the field "orderstatus" and "ordersales" and return anything that contains the value im looking for. So YES it should be applied for both fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add each field you want to filter separately:

```
strFilter = "orderstatus LIKE '*xxx*' OR ordersales LIKE '*xxx*'"
```

Use OR if you want one or the other to contain the filter string, or AND if you want them both to have it.

Comment: Thanks  you guys so much! Ill try :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use wildcards on both fields you need to apply the criteria separately to both fields

**Something like this:**

```
Private Sub txtFilter_AfterUpdate()  

     Dim strFilter As String
     Dim strWildcard As String
     If Len(Trim(Me.txtfilter.Value & vbNullString)) > 0 Then
        strWildcard = " Like '*" & Replace(Me.txtfilter.Value, "'", "''") & "*'"
        strFilter = "orderstatus" & strWildcard  & " And ordersales"  & strWildcard 
        Me.Filter = strFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
     Else
        Me.FilterOn = False
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you guys so much! Ill try :)

Comment: Well i tried. Thanks for the swift reply. It doesn't seem to work though.
Now when i enter something in the field, press enter, it just doesnt do anything really. On top of the vba page i have this also:

    Option Compare Database
    Option Explicit

That has no impact i guess.

Comment: What are YOU trying to accomplish with the filter? What value is in your txtFilter - and should it be applied to BOTH fields?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! dbmitch answered with a full on code thats correct, only i set the AND to OR so it searching either field. Thank you!

Private Sub txtFilter_AfterUpdate()

```
 Dim strFilter As String
 Dim strWildcard As String
 If Len(Trim(Me.txtfilter.Value & vbNullString)) > 0 Then
    strWildcard = " Like '*" & Replace(Me.txtfilter.Value, "'", "''") & "*'"
    strFilter = "orderstatus" & strWildcard  & " And ordersales"  & strWildcard 
    Me.Filter = strFilter
    Me.FilterOn = True
 Else
    Me.FilterOn = False
 End If
```

End Sub